Extract text after last delimiter but exclude last character
I'm needing to extract a couple of pieces of text from a text field that sometimes contains multiple of the same delimiter. I need characters 3-6 and then the text from the end, but I also don't want the last character.
Example:
1-7483742 (first part of the string-second part of the string)
1-1234742 (first part of the string-some other part)
1-5678742 (first part of the string-and more text)
Results needed:
7483 second part of the string
1234 some other part
5678 and some more text
Among other things, I have tried this:
=IFERROR(RIGHT(LEFT([@[sourcecolumn]],6),4)&" "&
MID([@[sourcecolumn]], FIND("-", [@[sourcecolumn]], FIND("-", [@[sourcecolumn]])+1)+1,256),
RIGHT(LEFT([@[sourcecolumn]],6),4))

This gets me the closest but it keeps the last character.

Try : =MID(A2,3,4) or =LEFT(TEXTAFTER(A2,"-"),4) or =REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"[\d+]{4}",1)

Are you looking for DAX?

thank you for your response! Your answer doesn't seem to answer the whole question...

Neither your question is sufficient here to have a proper answer because, you need to post some examples as well as reason out the logic. Which is missing, also you have not confirmed whether you are looking for a solution DAX or specifically Excel Formulas ? BTW the response, given is working on my end based on one example you have given.

Your answer only provides the numbers, but not the text that occurs later in the string. The output should be
"7483 second part of the string"
I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Kindly post few more examples with expected output. it helps !

Will do! I have added some more examples to the question...

Thanks!, Try this : =LET(α, CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A2,{"-","(",")"},,1),2,4), LEFT(TAKE(α,,1),4)&" "&TAKE(α,,-1))

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This works on my end:


=LET(
     α, CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"-","(",")"},,1),2,4), 
     LEFT(TAKE(α,,1),4)&" "&TAKE(α,,-1))


• For Older Versions could use the following:
=MID(A1,3,4)&" "&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),"-",REPT(" ",100)),100))



If you have Microsoft 365, we could use TEXTAFTER etc. TEXTAFTER function - Microsoft Support
Also, I prefer to define names for input ranges and create functions as they can be reused.
With BYROW we can give a range as input, avoiding to fill down the formula. _input in the named range with text.
=LAMBDA(_input,
BYROW(_input, LAMBDA(_input,
LET(
_part1, LEFT(TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(_input, "("),"-"), 4),
_part2, TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(_input, ")"), {"(","-"},3),
TEXTJOIN(" ",,_part1, _part2)
))))(_input)

Hope this helps.

